# disable or remove the "messages and communication history" from fleet module

Tags: odoo

I want to uninstall the module "social network" but it is in dependence with "fleet" module so now i only want to disable or remove the "messages and communication history" from this module.

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible without changing core code - fleet module inherits from mail.thread so that messaging is possible and you would have to remove that inheritance and remove all references to message_follower_ids and message_ids in all XMLs in which they have been used.

Comment: yes i know but now i only want to disable "messages and communication history" for graphic interface of the module fleet.

Comment: If for graphic interface, then inheriting to XML file and removing message_follower_ids and message_ids from views will be enough for you.

Comment: @mehdi Mokni  you can inherite that view from your module and hide that fields  using xpath definatelly u can do using position="replace" attribute in xpath